# Bind to property in custom control

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a custom control `CustomTextBox.xaml`:

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Core.Controls.CustomTextBox"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Core.Controls;assembly=MyApp.Core"
         BackgroundColor="White">

<AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped"/>
</AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>

<Entry x:Name="textValueEntry" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 1, 0.9, 0.9" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
<Label x:Name="placeholderLabel" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.05, 0.5" FontSize="18"/>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I want to be able to bind to the `textValueEntry` control from the parent view. So I added a bindable property in `CustomTextBox.xaml.cs`:

```
private string _textValue;
public string TextValue
{
    get
    {
        return _textValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _textValue = value;
    }
}

public static BindableProperty TextValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextValue), typeof(string), typeof(CustomTextBox), string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay, null,
                                                                 (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
                                                                 {
                                                                     (bindable as CustomTextBox).textValueEntry.Text = (string)newValue;
                                                                 });
```

I try to bind to it from the parent view like this:

```
<controls:CustomTextBox HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" TextValue="{Binding UsernamePropertyInViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

`TextValue` property gets set with `UsernamePropertyInViewModel` when I launch the app, as I can see it in `textValueEntry`. But when I change the text in `textValueEntry` it doesn't update `UsernamePropertyInViewModel`. How can I bind to it so it updates `UsernamePropertyInViewModel` when I change the text in `textValueEntry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell your `CustomTextBox` entry `textValueEntry` doesn't **Bind** to your TextValue property.

Also your `TextValue` property needs to look like this for `BindableProperties`. You need to set your **BindableProperty** to the appropriate value for a Binding. No need for a private backing variable to `TextValue`.

```cs
public string TextValue
{
    get => (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextValueProperty, value);
}
```

**Parent.Xaml**

```
<Entry x:Name="textValueEntry" Text="{Binding Path=TextValue, Source={x:Reference Page}}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 1, 0.9, 0.9" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

Your Page will need an x:Name="Page" for the `Binding Source`